# How to affect only changed folders and files when run `post-checkout` hook?

Tags: git

I want to set full permission after checkout.`post-checkout` script as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This is post-checkout hook"
checkoutType=$3
find -not -path "./git/*" -exec chmod -R a+rwx {} \;
```

But this script chmod everything, will spend lots of time.
How to chmod only changed folders and files after `checkout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advanced `find`!

```
find -not -path "./git/*" -not -perm 0777 -exec chmod -R a+rwx {} \;
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As you probably have imagined, yes, this is as intuitive as it looks - it tells `find` to only work on files and directories that don't have 0777 (or `rwxrwxrwx`) permission.

Alternatively, to avoid excessive invocations of `chmod`, you can use `xargs`:

```
find -not -path "./git/*" -not -perm 0777 -print0 | xargs -0 chmod a+rwx
```

With a few tweaking to `xargs`, you'll run `chmod` only once, saving a lot of time and increasing the overall performance. See `max xargs` for more information.

Comment: simple and solid answer.Any disadvantage to excessive invocations of chmod?

Comment: @kittygirl `chmod` is usually a binary in `/bin`, so invoking it repeatedly is usually a waste of time when you can just call it once and let it handle all the files in one run

Comment: @kittygirl At the very least, I believe piping + processing command line arguments is *much* faster than running a binary for *every* single file you `find`.

Comment: Is `find -not -path "./git/*" -not -perm 0777 -print0 | xargs -0 chmod a+rwx` better?

Comment: Use builtin (into find) xargs replacing `;` with `+`: `find -not -path "./git/*" -not -perm 0777 -exec chmod -R a+rwx {} \+`

Comment: @iBug,`find -not -path "./git/*"` will also include `./.git`.How to exclude `./.git` folder and anything within this folder.

Comment: @iBug,your answer use `./git/*"`,should it be `./.git/*`?

Comment: @kittygirl Yep. I just copied your code from the question and didn't notice that.